# How to Redirect permantly to another page after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Hello I wanted to know how I can make a protect a page and redirect to other pages after a form submission like.
http://ranksurveys.com/users/signup
they are doing here after u submitted the form u can not access that page again.. and you will auto redirected to http://ranksurveys.com/surveys 
I am really curious hope someone can help me!

Comment: and you also can't access the home page anymore it also redirects you to  http://ranksurveys.com/surveys

Comment: using `javascript` use `window.location = "http://yoursite.com/yourpage" ` or use `php header("Location ")`

Comment: I am looking for a specific way to protect a page when the form on it has been submitted in the past by a user... With protect I mean if the form on the page protected has been submitted in the past or they landed on the Thank you page in the past they can't access the Protected page anymore and will be redirected to the thank you page...
For an example check the links I posted :
Protected form page:
http://ranksurveys.com/users/signup

Thank you page:
http://ranksurveys.com/surveys

Comment: When you succesfully submit the form on the protected page you can't access it anymore and and will be redirected to the Ty page

Comment: so if the user has signed up, then if he want's to open the sign up page again he'll be redirected ?

Comment: yes exactly thats what I want but I can't figure out how they do it

Comment: What server side framework/cms you are using

Comment: i checked your links, on `http://ranksurveys.com/surveys` there is a redirect to `login` page when the user is not logged in ! is this what you want ?

Comment: this is done by setting opening the page only if a `php` `session` is registered (meaning user has logged in)

Comment: You mean the sign up page? http://ranksurveys.com/users/signup
 there is no login page as far as I know.
What I want is when u sign up on that page you can't access the page anymore and will be auto redirected to : http://ranksurveys.com/surveys
and if you didnt sign up yet and you try to access : http://ranksurveys.com/surveys they auto redirect you to the sign up page:  http://ranksurveys.com/users/signup

Comment: as far as I know the "password" is fake and it is send to an autoresponder database with the firstname and email

Comment: @Tim use Jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies. Whether it can be use as server side or client side. This can be easily approach with Jquery cookies.

step 1 : add script files

```
<head>
 <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>
```

step 2: in the protected form page add this script

```
var isProtected = $.cookie('page-protected');
if(isProtected == 'YES'){
  // We dont need to stay them on current page if they have already submitted the form
  window.location = "http://yoursite.com/your-thanking-page";
}

$.cookie('page-protected', 'NO');
```

step 3: in the thanking page you should set the cookie **YES** if the relevant form submitted successfully.

```
if(formSubmitComplete){
  $.cookie('page-protected', 'YES');
}
```

Comment: Thanks man this works fine!

Comment: Congrats.. choose the answer if its worked for u :)

Answer (score 0):

When user submits the form you just put information that form were submitted into the cookies session. Before rendering the form you just check the values in cookie\session and if you found that the form were already submitted just send Location and redirect status code via PHP. You should avoid implementing this in JS because anyone can easily disable Javascript in the browser.

Here is some ugly but fast code exmaples just to explain the concept
 1. Retrieving the form

```
    /* These are our valid username and passwords */
$user = 'jonny4';
$pass = 'delafoo';

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password')) {

    if (($_POST['username'] == $user) && ($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {    

        if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
            /* Set cookie to last 1 year */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/account', 'www.example.com');
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), time()+60*60*24*365, '/account', 'www.example.com');

        } else {
            /* Cookie expires when browser closes */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], false, '/account', 'www.example.com');
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), false, '/account', 'www.example.com');
        }
        header('Location: index.php');

    } else {
        echo 'Username/Password Invalid';
    }

} else {
    echo 'You must supply a username and password.';
}
```

2. Access cookie and redirect to login if not logged in. I hope you'll understand how to implement an opposite case ;)

   /* These are our valid username and passwords */
   $user = 'jonny4';
   $pass = 'delafoo';

   if (isset($_COOKIE[['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password')) {

   ```
   if (($_POST['username'] != $user) || ($_POST['password'] != md5($pass))) {    
       header('Location: login.html');
   } else {
       echo 'Welcome back ' . $_COOKIE['username'];
   }
   ```

   } else {
       header('Location: login.html');
   }

Comment: Hey thanks for your reaction I really like the idea of using php instead of js but I can't seem to get it to work mind going in details on how to implement this?